# Why does itemconfig show numbers instead of variable?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I tried to make an entry field and save it in a variable for putting it in a `Canvas`, but when I type my text and I submit it, there a lot of numbers that appear. I don't understand why.

[image: Before I type and submit text]

[image: After I type and submit a text]

And that's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

fen=Tk()
can=Canvas(fen, width=600, height=400, background="light pink")
def rep():
 reponse.get()
 can.itemconfig(banque,text= reponse)
banque=can.create_text(300,200, text="Nothing")
reponse=Entry(fen)
reponse.pack()
b=Button(fen, text="Submit",command=rep)
b.pack()
can.pack()
fen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
def rep():
 reponse.get()
 can.itemconfig(banque,text= reponse)
```

with:

```
def rep():
    can.itemconfig(banque, text=reponse.get())
```

Since `reponse` is still the *reference* to the `Entry` which has a valid `str` representation which can be used as a string value to be displayed.

Additionally, `entry_widget.get()` returns a string. It doesn't modify anything by itself, it simply just returns the string written inside the `entry_widget`.

The number you're seeing is the reference to the entry object in the `Tcl` interpreter.